# Good job "on or in" something

Tags: prepositions

I have seen both being used. But I don't know when to use which one.

> 1- You have done a good job ***on*** this (Context: Your teacher
>   saying this after he examines your homework)
>
> 1a- You have done a good job ***in*** this
>
> 2- He did a good job ***on*** stealing the ball. (Context: Commentor
>   saying this during a basketball game.)
>
> 2a- He did a good job ***in*** stealing the ball.
>
> 3- I think I did a good job ***on*** it (Context: You are saying this
>   after have finished writing a code.)
>
> 3a- I think I did a good job ***in*** it

Comment: I can think of some contrived examples where *in* might work (*"How well did he do when in the box?" "I think he did a good job when in it."*), but they are contrived. So, while not actually ungrammatical, the use of that preposition is unlikely in most situations. On the other hand, I would expect *with* to be used at least as often as *on* in many contexts. (While *in* would be quite uncommon.)

Comment: For example: "You did a good job in answering my question".

Comment: *You did a good job **in** answering my question* doesn't sound entirely natural to me—although, it's not outright wrong.

Comment: So using "on" in the all examples above is right and natural to you? And are you a AmE speaker or BE speaker?

Comment: As I said in my first comment, *on* sounds fine, as does *with* in some of the sentences. Both sound more natural to me than *in*.

Comment: Thank you, could I take your opinion about using "of" in those examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER**

*Use “on” 90% of the time.*

“On” tells us what you did a good job on. “In” can tell us where or when you did a good job.

**LONG ANSWER**

(In this answer, I’ll treat “good job,” “good work,” “great job,” and “great work,” as the same word. They all mean pretty much the same exact thing.)

**”On” is the most natural word almost all of the time.** It connects the “Good job” to what you did a good job on.

1. “I did a good job on the test” = I scored well on the test
2. “They were doing a good job on the drawing” = Their drawing was good
3. “Great job on the field!” = You built/tilled a field and it is well-done
4. “Good work on choir class!” = You designed a choir class syllabus and it is well-done

“In” might be useful as in the following examples:

1. “I did a good job in the position” = While in the position, I did a good job
2. “They did a good job in their time here.” = While they were here, they did a good job
3. “Great work in the field!” = While in the field, you did a good job (saving lives/building houses/planting wheat)
4. “Good job in choir class!” = While in choir class, you did a good job (singing/teaching/doodling)

In these examples, you’re using “in” to describe **where (or when) you did a good job, not to introduce what you did a good job on.** You can use other words to describe this where or when as well:

1. “Great job at the tournament last week!” = While at the tournament, you did well
2. “Great work at school today!” = While at school, you did well

Hope this helped! Comment any questions and I’ll get back to you.

Comment: Note that the "in" or "at" has nothing to do with "good job" specifically. You could just as easily say "I painted the walls blue in my time in the position", "I saw you in choir class" or "They continually talked about ducks in their time here". When you are talking about the thing which you did well at, it is **always** "good job on", or maybe "good job of". It is never "good job in". Never never never.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen "do a good job in", and it reads like a mistake to me.

Comment: For example: "You did a good job in answering my question".

Comment: I have never seen that usage. I would know what you mean, but think it was strange.

Comment: Folks, if you're going to downvote then please provide feedback. I'm a native speaker, and I have *never* seen "do a good job in".